# Creating longer array if elements contain whitespaces? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, whitespace

currently I'm trying to make a method that does the following:

- Takes 3 String Arrays (words, beforeList, and afterList)
- Looks for words that are in both words and in beforeList, and if found, replaces with word in afterList
- Returns a new array that turns the elements with characters in afterList into new elements by themselves

For example, here is a test case, notice that "i'm" becomes split into two elements in the final array "i" and "am":

```
    String [] someWords = {"i'm", "cant", "recollect"};
    String [] beforeList = {"dont", "cant", "wont", "recollect", "i'm"};
    String [] afterList = {"don't", "can't", "won't", "remember", "i am"};
    String [] result = Eliza.replacePairs( someWords, beforeList, afterList);
    if ( result != null && result[0].equals("i") && result[1].equals("am") 
            && result[2].equals("can't") && result[3].equals("remember")) {
        System.out.println("testReplacePairs 1 passed.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("testReplacePairs 1 failed.");
    }
```

My biggest problem is in accounting for this case of whitespaces. I know the code I will post below is wrong, however I've been trying different methods. I think my code right now should return an empty array that is the length of the first but accounted for spaces. I realize it may require a whole different approach. Any advice though would be appreciated, I'm going to continue to try and figure it out but if there is a way to do this simply then I'd love to hear and learn from it! Thank you.

```
public static String[] replacePairs(String []words, String [] beforeList, String [] afterList) {
    if(words == null || beforeList == null || afterList == null){
        return null;
    }
    String[] returnArray;
    int countofSpaces = 0;
    /* Check if words in words array can be found in beforeList, here I use     
       a method I created "inList". If a word is found the index of it in                    
       beforeList will be returned, if a word is not found, -1 is returned.
       If a word is found, I set the word in words to the afterList value */
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        int listCheck = inList(words[i], beforeList);
        if(listCheck != -1){
            words[i] = afterList[listCheck];
        }
    }
    // This is where I check for spaces (or attempt to)
    for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++){
        if(words[j].contains(" ")){
            countofSpaces++;
        }
    }
    // Here I return an array that is the length of words + the space count)
    returnArray = new String[words.length + countofSpaces];
    return returnArray;

}
```

Comment: Questions of the form "here's some code, tell me what's wrong" are generally off-topic on StackOverflow.  You need to do some basic work before posting.  First, step through your code in an IDE debugger to identify where it isn't behaving the way you expect.  Then ask ONE specific question, describing what you expect to happen and how that differs from what actually happened (i.e. show expected and actual output).  I _think_ I understand that your problem has to do with the substitution `i am` needing to occupy 2 output array positions, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you have to take into account if the input contains words with more than 1 consecutive space?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I can edit the post to the best of my ability. And no, I believe it's just if whitespace is in between then delete the whitespace and make two seperate array elements in the new array

Comment: To Jim, I believe I specified my issue: "my biggest problem is in accounting for whitespace". I also stated what the method should do. I also commented "this is where I check for spaces (or try to). Is there a specific part that is unclear?

Comment: *"My biggest problem is in accounting for this case of whitespaces."* - I don't know what you mean by this. *" I think my code right now should return an empty array that is the length of the first but accounted for spaces."* - I don't know what you mean by this.  (An empty array has length zero.  Always.  That's what "empty array" means.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one of the many ways of doing it, assuming you have to handle cases where words contain more than 1 consecutive spaces:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        int listCheck = inList(words[i], beforeList);
        if(listCheck != -1){
            words[i] = afterList[listCheck];
        }
    }

    ArrayList<String> newWords = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++) {
        String str = words[i];
        if(str.contains(' ')){
            while(str.contains("  ")) {
                str = str.replace("  ", " ");
            }

            String[] subWord = str.split(" ");

            newWords.addAll(Arrays.asList(subWord));
        } else {
            newWords.add(str);
        }
    }

    return (String[])newWords.toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look :)